# How do you declare an array of Qt.points in QML?

Tags: arrays, qt, qml, qt-quick

In the C++ class I have something like this (I've tried different things):

```
class X : public QObject  {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void save(int _n, QObject *_points);
```

I tried this in the qml file, but it dosen't compile:

```
property var Qt.point points: []
```

I want to pass this array from QML (in a javascript function) to a C++ function like this:

```
x.save(root.points.length, root.points)
```

If I declare points like this:

```
property var points: []
```

the C++ function is called, but points is NULL.

Comment: How were you adding the points to the array? 
property var points: [] and then
points.push(Qt.point(pointX, pointY)) should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
property var Qt.point points: []
```

That makes no sense, the syntax is property + type + name. `Qt.point` is not a type but a function that returns an object of type `point`. And a `var` that contains a JS array most certainly will not be converted to a `QObject *` in C++.

I suggest you implement your array of points as a C++ class, with accessor functions to access or manipulate the data from QML. So you will have a `QVector<QPoint>` in your `X` class, along with functions to get the size, get or set points, append, prepend, insert and whatnot.  So when you call `save()` you can directly access the C++ data. That would be the most efficient solution.